# Intel optimized Python on Machine Learning Service Compute

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to run a Python script or Estimator step on the Azure Machine Learning Service in a container with the intel optimized Python distribution?
I understand this is available on the [Azure Data Science VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/intel-and-microsoft-bring-optimizations-to-deep-learning-on-azure/) ([or described here](https://www.intel.ai/intel-optimized-data-science-virtual-machine-azure/#gs.yuntlp)), but I could not find out how to use this as an Azure Machine Learning Service Compute target.

For my current use case I am specifically interested in using an mkl linked numpy package in the aml service container.

Note: Running numpy.show_config() inside the container suggests numpy is linked against openblas and not mkl

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Azure ML base images use [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) Python distribution, which uses MKL.

You can find the details of the base images here:https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers

Also, if you install using Anaconda numpy in following way

```
conda_dep.add_conda_package("numpy")
runconfig.run_config.environment.python.conda_dependencies = conda_dep
```

you should see this kind of output from `numpy.show_config()`.

> blas_mkl_info:
>
> libraries = ['blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'pthread', 'blas', 'cblas',
>   'lapack']
>
> library_dirs =
>   ['/azureml-envs/azureml_a8ad8e485613e21e6e8adc1bfda86b40/lib']
>
> define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>
> include_dirs =
>   ['/azureml-envs/azureml_a8ad8e485613e21e6e8adc1bfda86b40/include']

Comment: However, when I run numpy.show_config() inside the container the output suggests numpy is linked against openblas and not mkl.

Comment: From the Dockerfile on the github repo I can seen the Miniconda version. But could you point me to the documentation that says that numpy in miniconda is in fact linked to mkl? I was not able to find this.

Comment: The Anaconda numpy should be linked to MKL: https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/

Comment: @phonosync I added some more details to my answer how to get the MKL enabled numpy. Please let me know if this is not working for you and we can debug deeper.

Comment: I can confirm that the conda packages are indeed linked to MKL and I get the same output from np.show_config() as per @Roope answer. My problem was that I used pip packages.